# parse string date to jodaDateTime

Tags: datetime, jodatime

I am having an issue converting a string date to joda DateTime object

my date format is

```
   fromDate:2015-10-16T00:00:00.000+05:30
   toDate:2015-10-17T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

i dont know which date format pattern to use , convert this to datetime object , i m able to convert when i have separate integers coming like this

```
       fromDate = new DateTime().withDate(params?.fromDate_year.toInteger(), params?.fromDate_month.toInteger(), params?.fromDate_day.toInteger()).withTimeAtStartOfDay()
        toDate =  new DateTime().withDate(params?.toDate_year.toInteger(), params?.toDate_month.toInteger(), params?.toDate_day.toInteger()).withTimeAtStartOfDay()
```

how can i convert my string to date ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this simply, joda library will handle everything for you, you just need to pass your string date to DateTime()

```
  String fromDate = "2015-10-16T00:00:00.000+05:30"
  String toDate = "2015-10-17T00:00:00.000+05:30"
  fromDate = new DateTime(fromDate);
  toDate = new DateTime(toDate);
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

To continue on what @roanjain said, Joda will take care of parsing such a string just fine, however, the DateTime object created will show the default timezone. If your computer is not in the "Asia/Kolkata" timezone you need to tell Joda that you want a DateTime in that timezone, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time = "2015-10-16T00:00:00.000+05:30";
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(time);
    // Will show whatever time zone you are in
    System.out.println(dt);
    // Same point in time, but represented in a different time zone
    System.out.println(dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata")));
    // Create a DateTime object in the requested timezone
    dt = new DateTime(time).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"));
    System.out.println(dt);
}
```

Note that both timestamps represent the same point in time, and will remain properly comparable.